# Browser page getting unresponsive or hanged after sometime using socket.io, NodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, performance, socket.io

I my browser page getting slow or hanged or you can say unresponsive after sometime like one hour or 2 hours. Actually my requirement is to use socket.io for notifications from server.

I have setup a NodeJS with Express, mysql, mysql-event redis and socket.io, wherever any record inserted into database a notification has to be sent to the client application. On the client application i am creating li element every time when notification received and remove every 12th element.

Record are inserting into table very fast like 30 record per second.

Everything working fine, but after sometime browser page which showing notification getting slow or hanged sometimes google chrome says ran out of memory and kill the page.

I thing its a problem of browser, memory-leaks and client side scripting not NodeJs Server.

Please suggest me what to do to optimize client application as i am adding 30 li DOM element and removing same per second basis.

**Code**

```
 socket.on('connect', function(){ 
     console.log("Client Connected.");
     socket.on("my-channel", function(msg){ 
         if(msg == null){
                console.log("MSG is Null");
                return;
            }
        $('ul.add_elem').prepend('<li'+clr+'>'+data+'</li>');
                                $('ul.add_elem li').eq(0).animate({
                                    'opacity':1,
                                    'max-width':'350px',
                                    'padding-left':'10px',
                                    'padding-right':'40px'
                                }, 200);

                                $('ul.add_elem li').eq(11).fadeOut(100);
                                $('ul.add_elem li').eq(12).remove();
//         adding notification by creating DOM LI and removing 12th li Element as shown above code.

        msg = null;
       });
    });
```

Comment: Do you store all your notifications in a JS object on the client side ?

Comment: i have updated my code, kindly check.

Comment: I would try inspecting memory usage, that way you will know if there is a leak somewhere.

Comment: Ok, let me try.